# Style rule is applied to wrong element

Tags: html, css

I have the following rule which targets the level 0 last li child ul. For some odd reason the following rule also applies the styling to other element. I' am also attaching the screenshot.

```
#primary-menu ul li:last-child ul{
    left: -139%;
}
```

As you can see below, the style above is also applied to the `Our Memebers` children ul. The `Talk to Us` children ul styling is working fine. 
[image]

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="primary-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="nav nav-justified">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Members</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Member Countries</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">American Samoa</a></li>
                  ....
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">How to Become a member</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
                  ....
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Interim Members</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Bouganville</a></li>
                  ....
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Regional NGO’s</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Observers</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Hawaii</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Our Donors</a></li>
              ....
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Talk to Us</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Our Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong in the style rule?

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Maverick976 I have updated the question with HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might need to increase specificity a bit:

```css
#primary-menu #menu-primary-menu > li:last-child ul {
    left: -139%;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t99qzms/).  I changed the background color so you can see the difference (since we are missing the rest of your css file).

Comment: Thank you very much Maverick976 it works like a charm. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#primary-menu > ul > li:last-child ul {
  left: -139%;
}
```

Comment: @DevilRaily, Edited.